# Selenium Webdrier using Java: Exception while reading from Excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using SeleniumWebDriver using Java to automation one of the portal applications. As part of this, I want to read username and password from Excel and written below code. But seeing `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/ThemeDocument` Below is the code

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.util.Random;

    public class BankingFaceLift {
        static WebDriver  driver = null;


        public static void main(String[]args){

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://obsit.enbduat.com/obweb/common/login.jsf?faces-redirect=true");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            try
            {    
                File file = new File("TestData.xlsx");
                FileInputStream iFile = new FileInputStream(file);

                XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(iFile);
                XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

                int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
                System.out.println("the no of rows are : " + rowCount);
                for (int row=1; row<=rowCount; row++)
                {

                    String Username = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                    String Password = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(Username);
                    driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt49")).sendKeys(Password);
                    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
```

I have imported `poi-xxx.jar` and `poi-ooxml.jar1`.

Kindly advice Thanks!

Comment: Please share the complete exception

Comment: Please find complete exception ` Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/ThemeDocument
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:59)
 at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:465)`

Comment: problem in some where, either your project / package

Comment: @ prabu.. can you please be specific when you say problem with project / package ? I didn't get it. Can you please point where could be the issue

Comment: i think this exception in not related to poi,not an issue in the reading excel part

Comment: Ok. Thanks, Let me check because I'm still not sure what is the issue causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import poi-ooxml-schemas jar as well. You can download the jar from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpoiooxmlschemas39jar.htm)